# Navbar hover if mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this Javascript code that i got on another thread on Stackoverflow but there is a small gap of about 1px when the mouse hits this between the navbar header and the actual dropdown then the dropdown will disappear.

I grabbed this code as if there is a mouse I would like it to hover, however if it is on mobile with no mouse then I would like the user to click to open the dropdown.

```
  //NAVBAR HOVER IF MOUSE, IF NOT CLICK
  $('body').on('mouseenter mouseleave', '.dropdown', function(e) {
    var _d = $(e.target).closest('.dropdown');
    _d.addClass('show');
    setTimeout(function() {
      _d[_d.is(':hover') ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('show');
      $('[data-toggle="dropdown"]', _d).attr(
        'aria-expanded',
        _d.is(':hover')
      );
    }, 300);
  });
```

Is there anyway I can add a delay to this to give the user time to get over this pixel window?

I'm not very experienced with Javascript/JQuery but thought the number towards the end (300) would be a timeout as this seems to be the end of the function so I increased this to 60000 but this did not make any difference.

Any help is appreciated. This is also developed within Bootstrap if that makes a difference.

Comment: Please add your HTML and CSS. Give us a chance to help you.

Comment: @KoshVery thank you for your help, I added a margin: 0 to my CSS and this fixed the issue. I have added this as the answer to help anyone in the future, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all of your help.

As you pointed to the CSS Kosh Very I had a look and added this code which has fixed my issue:

```
.dropdown > .dropdown-menu {
  margin: 0;
}
```

This has cleared the issue, thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about, I did nothing but asked to update your question. Happy to see you've found a solution by yourself.

Comment: Your prompt to look at the CSS made me think that I could just remove the margin in the CSS to fix my issue. As stated in my original question I am new to javascript so I think I was trying to over complicate the issue and fix it in the javascript when I could simply edit the CSS to resolve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

For delay you can use the [`Jquery.delay()][1]` Method. It will simply post delay before any event that comes after the call to `.delay` e.g.

```
$( "div.first" ).slideUp( 300 ).delay(500).fadeIn(2000)
```